# count frequent strings + python3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I got a question for you, first of all the code here:

```
from urllib import request
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize

URL = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-0.txt'

RESPONSE = request.urlopen(URL)
RAW = RESPONSE.read().decode('utf8')

print('\n')
type(RAW)
print('\n')
len(RAW)

TOKENS = word_tokenize(RAW)

print(type(TOKENS))
X = print(len(TOKENS))
print(TOKENS[:X])

print('\n')

c = Counter(RAW)
print(c.most_common(30))
```

Here is the first Output, I get. With that one I am satisfied.

```
['\ufeffThe', 'Project', 'Gutenberg', 'EBook', 'of', 'A', 'Christmas', 'Carol', ',', 'by', 'Charles',...]
```

Here is the **second part** of the output which do not makes me satisfied:

```
[(' strong text', 28438), ('e', 16556), ('t', 11960), ('o', 10940), ('a', 10092), ('n', 8868), ('i', 8791),...]
```

Here is my question: As you can see I am counting the most frequently occuring strings in a text, but the Problem is I want to count the whole elements of the list of words: The final part of second output should look something like that:

```
[('Dickens', 28438), ('Project', 16556), ('Gutenberg', 11960),...]
```

and not as you can see above in the second part of output. I want to show the 30 most frequently used Words in the text, and not parts of elements in elements of the list.

Do you know how I can solve that Problem? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this one

```
c = Counter(TOKENS)
```

Here attached your full code with change

```
from urllib import request
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize

URL = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-0.txt'

RESPONSE = request.urlopen(URL)
RAW = RESPONSE.read().decode('utf8')

print('\n')
type(RAW)
print('\n')
len(RAW)

TOKENS = word_tokenize(RAW)

print(type(TOKENS))
X = print(len(TOKENS))
print(TOKENS[:X])

print('\n')

c = Counter(TOKENS)
print(c.most_common(500))
```

Comment: Hey Thushara Dahanayake, thanks it works perfect, but I forgot to inform about splitting away commas, points and whitespaces. It does not work with "c = Counter(TOKENS.split('[,. ]')". You know how to do that. Sorry I am a beginner in python (I love the language itself) :)